# How to replicate a vuejs codepen locally?

Tags: vue.js, localhost

There is a Vuejs codepen I would like to run locally
(https://codepen.io/team/Vue/pen/oNXaoKy)

When I try to run it locally I get a different result from the codepen

[image] vs [image]

The code I have locally:

script.js

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      currentTab: 'Home',
      tabs: ['Home', 'Posts', 'Archive']
    }
  },
  computed: {
    currentTabComponent() {
      return 'tab-' + this.currentTab.toLowerCase()
    }
  }
})

app.component('tab-home', {
  template: `<div class="demo-tab">Home component</div>`
})
app.component('tab-posts', {
  template: `<div class="demo-tab">Posts component</div>`
})
app.component('tab-archive', {
  template: `<div class="demo-tab">Archive component</div>`
})

app.mount('#dynamic-component-demo')
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Component basics: dynamic components</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div id="dynamic-component-demo" class="demo">
  <button
     v-for="tab in tabs"
     v-bind:key="tab"
     v-bind:class="['tab-button', { active: currentTab === tab }]"
     v-on:click="currentTab = tab"
   >
    {{ tab }}
  </button>

  <component v-bind:is="currentTabComponent" class="tab"></component>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/vue@next'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
.demo {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  user-select: none;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.tab-button {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  margin-right: -1px;
}
.tab-button:hover {
  background: #e0e0e0;
}
.tab-button.active {
  background: #e0e0e0;
}
.demo-tab {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Any idea where am I going wrong? I know how to set up this whole thing with a vue-cli project, but I would like to know how to set up simple examples like these for rapid prototyping (without having to build projects, just with simple files)

Comment: did you try out to place `<script src='https://unpkg.com/vue@next'>` in head element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be sure you included the codepen ressources (css, js scripts, etc. links) in your html.

In the CodePen you want to reproduce, check out the settings: the only resource used is the cdn link to the Vue dependency.

> This kind of link targets a static file, here a javascript file, to download it manually instead of using some dependency manager like `npm`

In the `<head>` of your html, add this line:

```
<head>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
</head>
```